# like unlike button with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I was trying to create a like/unlike button in php using jquery. My code works fine. I have a like button and when I click on it, it transfers data to my "likes" table in my database. My only problem is that when I click on a **like button**, I cannot auto change to **unlike button**. Any idea how to do this?

This is my php code with like/unlike button:

```
<?php

$get_button = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `user`='$session_user_id' AND `the_comment_id`='{$row['comments_id']}'  ");                 

$get = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_button);

if($get==""){   
  <button class='button' id='like$comment_id'  style='color:grey;'>Like</button>
}else if($get!=""){
  <button class='button' id='unlike$comment_id' style='color:grey;'>Unlike</button>
}

?>
```

This is my jquery:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#like<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").click(function() { 
    var id = "<?php echo $comment_id; ?>";
    $.post("parse.php",{like:id}, function(data){

        $("#like<?php echo $comment_id; ?>");
        $(".button<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").html(data);          
    });

    $(this).hide();

  });


  $("#unlike<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").click(function() { 

     var id = "<?php echo $comment_id; ?>";
     $.post("parse.php",{unlike:id}, function(data){

      $("#unlike<?php echo $comment_id; ?>");
      $(".button<?php echo $comment_id; ?>").html(data);

     });

    $(this).hide();

  });


});

</script>
```

abd finally this is my parse.php script used by jquery to transfer data to database:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['like'])){
    $id = $_POST['like'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('', '$session_user_id', '$id') "); 
}

if(isset($_POST['unlike'])){
    $id = $_POST['unlike'];
    mysql_query(" DELETE FROM likes WHERE `user`='$session_user_id' AND `the_comment_id`='$id'  ");
}

?>
```

Comment: NOTE: mysql_* functions have been deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO instead, otherwise your application may be vulnerable to security risks!

Comment: "I cannot auto change to unlike button." What do you mean? You want like button to be hidden and unlike one to be shown or what? If you have at a time only one of them in DOM, then you need to delegate click event. Maybe if you provide rendered HTML markup, it would be easier to understand what you are looking for

Comment: I want like button to be hidden and unlike one to be shown

Comment: my problem is that if I press like, like button is hidden and I want to show unlike button instead. And the opposite

Answer (score 0):

try changing your first php script like this. it will work

```
<?php

$get_button = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `user`='$session_user_id' AND `the_comment_id`='{$row['comments_id']}'  ");                 

$get = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_button);

?>

<?php if($get==""): ?>  
      <button class='button' id='like<?php echo $comment_id; ?>'  style='color:grey;'>Like</button>
 <?php else if($get!=""): ?>
      <button class='button' id='unlike<?php echo $comment_id; ?>' style='color:grey;'>Unlike</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You cannot have html inside php like that